# Getting error when i call OpenGl in python

Tags: python, opengl, glu

when i try to import Opengl to my python code i get an error.
this is the error message:

```
from OpenGL.GLU.projection import *
```

---

```
  File "C:\Users\GAREH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.1.3b1-py3.7.egg\OpenGL\GLU\projection.py", line 3, in <module>
    from OpenGL import GL
  File "C:\Users\GAREH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.1.3b1-py3.7.egg\OpenGL\GL\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from OpenGL.GL.images import *
  File "C:\Users\GAREH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.1.3b1-py3.7.egg\OpenGL\GL\images.py", line 628, in <module>
    suffix, arrayConstant, getattr(GL_1_1,functionName),
  File "C:\Users\GAREH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.1.3b1-py3.7.egg\OpenGL\GL\images.py", line 578, in typedImageFunction
    if baseFunction:
  File "C:\Users\GAREH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.1.3b1-py3.7.egg\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 382, in __nonzero__
    self.load()
  File "C:\Users\GAREH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.1.3b1-py3.7.egg\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 397, in load
    force_extension = self.force_extension,
TypeError: constructFunction() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_extension'*
```

Comment: You are importing GLU, not OpenGL.

Comment: yes i face the same problem for  Glu, Glut and Gl

Comment: @harounbest not a python user but I think you should rearrange your imports as GLU and GLUT are depending on the GL so GL should be imported first .... In C++ I use this order: `#define GLEW_STATIC \r\n #include "glew.c" \r\n #include <gl\gl.h> \r\n #include <gl\glu.h> \r\n` ... In case you got correct order you might missing some header or define/switch before it ...

Comment: thnak you @Spektre, and yes you are right when it is about c++, but in pyhton it does not really matter

Comment: Do you import OpenGL.GL before GLU? Does that work?

Comment: yes @HughFisher i did, but it doesn't work either